# Get required output using SHLEX QUOTE

Tags: python, python-3.x, quoting

I am exploring functionality of **shlex quote** in python. Below are two examples,

```
>>> from shlex import quote
>>> str = 'C:/ProjectFiles/abc 1 - 426- abc.zip'
>>> quote(str)
"'C:/ProjectFiles/abc 1 - 426- abc.zip'"
>>> str = 'C:/ProjectFiles/'
>>> quote(str)
'C:/ProjectFiles/'
```

How do I make sure to remove the additional double quotes when quote() function is applied.

So, Instead of `"'C:/ProjectFiles/abc 1 - 426- abc.zip'"` I need `'C:/ProjectFiles/abc 1 - 426- abc.zip'`

I checked documentation but seems there is no option as such.

Answer (score 0):

There are no additional double quotes, that's just how Python represents a string that contains single quotes. For example:

```
>>> '\''
"'"
>>> print("'")
'
>>> print('C:/ProjectFiles/')
C:/ProjectFiles/
>>> print("'C:/ProjectFiles/abc 1 - 426- abc.zip'")
'C:/ProjectFiles/abc 1 - 426- abc.zip'
```

Comment: hmm..makes sense. I do got follow up question. If, I use the same `str` in python.subprocess call's argument list. It doesn't works. Code: `subprocess.check_output([str], shell = False)`

Comment: Well folders and zips aren't executable, so I'm not sure what you mean. BTW `str` is a bad variable name since it shadows the builtin `str`. Use something like `string` instead.